# C++ cannot declare variable to be of abstract type

Tags: c++

I'm using C++ template, and I got the error above.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
enum type{ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR,FIVE};

class base{
public:
    virtual void baseOut()const =0;
};
template<class T>
class derived:public base{
    virtual void drivedOut()const=0;
};

template<class T,type>
class derived2:public derived<T>{
    public:
    void baseOut(){}
    void drivedOut(){}

};

int main(){
    derived2<string,ONE> d;
    return 0;
}
```

My question is that since I have overrided pure virtual functions in the class template drived2, why is drived2 still an abstract class? How can I remove this error.

Thank you:)

Comment: Off topic: It is call "derived", not "drived"

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have modified it:)

Answer (score 14):

You haven't overriden `base::baseOut`, because `derived2::baseOut` is non-`const` !

```
void baseOut() const { }
//             ^^^^^
```

The same goes for `derived2::derivedOut`.

You should get in the habit of using `override` to catch these errors.

```
void baseOut() override { }       // Error, overrides nothing!
void baseOut() const override { } // OK
```

Clang is more helpful than GCC on this one:

```
main.cpp:18:14: warning: 'derived2<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, type::ONE>::baseOut'
                hides overloaded virtual function [-Woverloaded-virtual]
        void baseOut(){}
             ^

[...]

main.cpp:8:22: note: hidden overloaded virtual function 'base::baseOut' declared here:
               different qualifiers (const vs none)
        virtual void baseOut()const =0;
                     ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Overloading of function alsp depends on the constness of that function.

See http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/function-overloading-and-const-functions/

In you code

`virtual void baseOut()const =0;`    -- Const function

`void baseOut(){}` - non-const function.

Hence it is not function overriding (which you are expecting) but function overloading.
Due to which derived2 also becomes an abstract class, as function definition is not present for two virtual functions.

Comment: `baseOut` is not overloaded, but hidden. Even without the issue of the class becoming abstract, the `const` version is not visible in the derived class until you add it back into the overload set with `using`.